# From Python (3.6), copy file(s) with a given user's permission to a root controlled space

Tags: python, bash, file-permissions, sudo, dd

I have a problem and a solution, but frankly I'm not very happy with my solution and think there might be something better.

**What I want to achieve:**

I start as root (this will be executed from cron eventually). I want to copy a file with a given path, which belongs to a user over to a space that root controls (which implies a change in permissions). This file may be large. I also want to obey the file access permissions of the particular given user while I read the file, as the script will be acting on behalf of the user (and not a different user). I'd also like to do some sensible debugging should some part of this copy fail.

The rest of my code is Python, so ideally I'd like a pure Python way to do this.

In BASH, I can do it like this:

```
sudo -u <user> dd if=<in_file> | dd of=<out_file>
```

I have missed out some other flags to simplify things. Sudo looses scope after the pipe so the copied file is written out as root, which is what I want.

After that command, I can query ${PIPESTATUS[*]} to see if the first part or the second part failed, without having to try and parse the error messages.

**What I have done to Pythonize it**

```
templateDD="\
   sudo -u {user} \
   dd if=\'{inFile}\' bs={blockSize} status=none | \
   dd of=\'{outFile}\' status=none ; \
   echo ${{PIPESTATUS[*]}} \
"
subprocess.run(
   templateDD.format(**fileCopyD),
   shell=True,
   executable='/usr/bin/bash',
   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
   stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

I haven't included `fileCopyD`, but I'm sure imagination can fill that gap.

Returned is a CompletedProcess object with a single bytestring of the two pipe error states as stdout.

This is a bit ugly, in fact having to make system calls at all is unpleasant as one would rather control everything within Python. Secondly, this command is very dependant on BASH as the PIPESTATUS array is specific to that. In general it is good for code to be more portable, even if BASH is most places.

**My thoughts on better solutions**

1. The first part of this that I suspect can be improved is that I could probably get rid of the second `dd` and the querying of `PIPESTATUS`. The first dd would then be writing to stdout, which could probably be somehow captured, read into a buffer and written out to a file within the scope of Python code. I don't know how to do that though as even the `subprocess.run` command that I have used is at the edge of my experience.
2. I wonder if the `sudo -u <user>` could also be replaced by something in python though? I had a hint that I might be able to use `os.setuid` and `os.setgid`. My perceived problems with this are:

   - I need to look up the uid of the user, but the UIDs are not in passwd but come from SSSD.
   - I need to make sure that all group affiliations of the user are taken into account (also from SSSD).
   - I need to be confident that root has properly become the user with regard to all matters related to read access. I may not properly understand all environmental variables and such which must be set.

If problem 2 was solved, I guess that solves my BASH problem, but I need to make sure that the copied file is written with root permission.

Many thanks in advance for help on this.

Comment: "I start as root" -- you don't need `sudo` if you are root. why not just, e.g., `cp`?

Comment: The intent is to deliberately lower my level of permission to that of a particular user so that I can only access files that the user could.